# How to run on JBoss html file with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, jboss

I am creating a Static Web Project using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2.
My problem is that I have an HTML file (very simple, created automatically with Eclipse with HTML5 template) in this project and I would run it in an external browser (for example, Chrome) using as Server JBoss 7.1.

I have already configured properly JBoss in Eclipse, I can run/stop it without problems.
I have configured as Web Browser Chrome.

I don't know how run the single html file in my localhost:8080.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the project then you would have to deploy it.

Refer to http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/jboss-eclipse/jboss-and-eclipse?showall=&start=1 which describes how to deploy an application.

And your URL to the file would be `http://localhost:8080/yourProjectName/htmlFileName`

Example: `http://localhost:8080/TestApp/index.html`